# Index loaded into ui-view in AngularJS with UI-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am creating a site with AngularJS and everything works fine locally. Everything but this one thing works fine in the deployed version.

At one of the states 'orderinfo', 'index.html' is loaded in the ui-view instead of the partial in the routes.

Do any of you have any idea what might be going on?

```
// ...
state( 'order', {
            url: '/results/order/:id',
            templateUrl: 'views/order.html',
            controller: 'OrderController as order'
        } )
        .state( 'orderinfo', {
            url: '/results/order/edit/:id/:secret',
            templateUrl: 'views/orderinfo.html',
            controller: 'OrderInfoController as orderInfo'
        } )
        .state( 'orderconfirm', {
            url: '/results/order/confirm/:id/:secret',
            templateUrl: 'views/orderconfirm.html',
            controller: 'OrderConfirmController as orderconfirm'
        } )
// ...
```

Comment: what happens when you try to open url path to the actual template in browser

Comment: inspect actual ajax request for template in browser dev tools network for clues.

Comment: You were right! Looked at the wrong file there. One lowercase letter in the filename that needed to be uppercase. Haha! Thanks! The page didn't exist, so I was redirected to index, which messed things up.

Answer (score 0):

The filename was incorrect. It worked on the local development server because it was case insensitive, but not on the deployment server.